# Get url request with correct casing PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache

I don't really know if this is a PHP question, but let's say someone goes to my webpage via this URL:

```
exAMplE.exAMPlePage.com
```

Now the result from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable looks like this:

```
example.examplepage.com
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the requested URL with correct casing (as the user typed it)?

Maybe this can be done with `.htacces` but I don't know.

Edit: It's only the subdomain I care about.

Comment: Are you wanting the domain name, or the path within the URL?  Domain names are case-insensitive, the path isn't (but you can make your site not care about that).

Comment: Domain Name's  are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain names are not case sensitive, so the short answer is no.  Directories, files and get variables and values are case sensitive and will be returned as such.

If you notice, on all browsers that I have tried, the browser changes it to all lowercase.

Just curious, why does it matter?

Comment: I'm making a website where you can enter any subdomain, for example `xXx_MyGamerTag_xXx.examplepage.com`, and the page will display the subdomain. And the entered subdomain, which in this case is a username, usually don't look good without proper casing.
But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get it in a reliable way. Domain names are case insensitive; so the case in the URL typed by the visitor may be modified by the browser, or any of the proxies between the browser and your server.

Comment: Forgot to mention: It's only the subdomain I really care about. But I guess it's impossible then. Thanks for the answer.